Using volume data from OpenVDB format
I have a voxel volume of CT DICOM data in the Paraview application (screenshot 1), from which I exported in the OpenVDB format.
The CT data is 12 bit single channel grayscale information, I do not know how OpenVDB is storing the data though.
Which settings are needed in Blender to display the grayscale from the data ? Currently there is only a somewhat black cloud.

Paraview

Blender
